# Why isn't child's state changing to 'blue'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this small [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-zhukovsky-47gwk?file=/src/Child.js:172-214), I question why child's state isn't updated to blue when I click on the button. Is it because:

When a parent (functional) component re-executes (perhaps as a result of its state changing), its child component executes. However, the `[state, setState] = useState(newPropFromParent)` line, in the child, is not necessarily run again. (That line's only run again when the child's state changes?) Perhaps it's for this reason we're encouraged to store as much state as you can 'at the top' and pass it down as props?

Same code as sandbox:

```js
export default function App() {
  let [color, setColor] = useState("red");

  function updateColor() {
    setColor("blue");
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={updateColor}>Change color state to blue.</button>
      <Child givenColor={color} />
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function Child({ givenColor }) {
  let [color, setColor] = useState(givenColor);
  console.log("Child function executed");
  return (
    <>
      <div>{color}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

P.S. Primarily interested in knowing if my understanding is correct rather than receiving a solution to a hypothetical problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Child component is rendering the value of the **local** variable named `color` which is read from the state.

The first time the Child component is rendered, `useState(givenColor)` notes that no state exists and sets it to `givenColor("red")`.

When the button is clicked, the `givenColor` prop is changed to `"blue"` and the Child component is rerendered.

`let [color, setColor] = useState(givenColor);` then reads the color **from the state**  (which was previously set to `"red"`) and ignores the **new** default value.

---

If you want to use the value from the prop, then *just* use it. Don't involve state.

```
export default function Child({ givenColor }) {
  console.log("Child function executed");
  return (
    <>
      <div>{givenColor}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Right, it seems like the only time the arg in `useState(arg)` is used is in initial execution

Comment: @tonitone120 — Yes, it is only used when nothing is stored in the state.

Answer (score 1):

In your case is taking only the first value at the first rending of the two components, it's sufficient to define one state in parent and pass the prop that's reactive to the child JSX :

```
export default function Child({ givenColor }) {
 
  console.log("Child function executed");
  return (
    <>
      <div>{givenColor }</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

if the passed prop is used in combination with child component state you should use `useEffect` to make the changes